# How to import react native project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I started development of the android application using `atom` text editor. It is working fine as long I am writing code in JS and JSX.

I have to do functionality which is not available in react native, so I need to write java code as like https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

**ToastModule.java**

```
package com.facebook.react.modules.toast;

import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

import java.util.Map;

public class ToastModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

  private static final String DURATION_SHORT_KEY = "SHORT";
  private static final String DURATION_LONG_KEY = "LONG";

  public ToastModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
  }
}
```

I do not want to code Java in `atom` as suggestions are not working. Can we import our react native project in android studio where all in built classes of react native are available so I can have suggestion of classes/methods while writing code.

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Go to Android Studio--> then open the Android folder of your RN project

If you want code suggestions, Android Studio will help you while typing ;)

Comment: what i need to do if i want to my react project can be done for IOS?

Comment: the process is very similar but in XCode, just import the ios folder @famfamfam

Answer (score 24):

Yes, just open android studio. Then *Open an existing Android Studio project*, select *android* folder of your react native project.

Comment: I had to do a forceSync from ResourceManager to let androidStudio set the project up . It didn't do it by default.

Comment: When I try to run the project from AndroidStudio, it says : "reactnative" not found on the build console.