# how can i import or open react-native project in android studio?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I'm trying to import or open react-native project in android studio.

My project name is cooking2-master.

However, I am confused whether I need to import the entire project i.e (cooking2-master) or the android in the project.

This is my android studio image

[image]

What should I import ? cooking2-master(which is my entire project folder)? or  android in my project folder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import react native project in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43625874/how-to-import-react-native-project-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps to open a react native app on Android Studio:

1. Open Android Studio
2. Click `Open an Existing Project`
3. Browse to the folder with the react native project
4. Click the `android` folder INSIDE the react native project folder
5. Click `Open`

The important bit is that you open the `android` folder inside the react native project, not the react native folder itself.